# Angle between lines in Hyperbolic Geometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I have the following hyperbolic lines and I'm asked to find the angle between them.
The lines are $ε_0 = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}: Im(z) >0, Re(z) = 0\}$ and $ε_{1,2} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z-1| = 2\}$.

With some algebra I found that they intersect in $w = 0 + \sqrt3i$. So, drawing a line from the center of $ε_{1,2}$ to $w$ I create triangle with its vertices being the origin(O), the center of $ε_{1,2}$ and $w$(shape below). I'm asked to find the angle($θ$) created by the line I drew from the center of $ε_{1,2}$ and $ε_0$. Using the law of cosines, i find that $1^2 = 2^2 + \sqrt3^2 - 2*2*\sqrt3*cos(θ) \rightarrow cos(θ) = \sqrt3/2 \rightarrow θ = π/6$, but the book's answer is $-π/3$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The point $w$ you wrote is surely wrong. You mean $w=\sqrt{3}i$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Fixed.

Comment: You are asked to find the angle between the vertical line $\epsilon_0$ and the circle $\epsilon_{1,2}$. I think you have found the angle between the vertical line and the *radius* of the circle instead.